# Optimize Exists and not exists

Tags: mysql, select, exists

Please help me to optimize the Mysql query

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT t0.ID, 
t0.CODE_MEANING, 
t0.CODE_SCHEME_DESIGNATOR, 
t0.CODE_SCHEME_VERSION, 
t0.CODE_VALUE, 
t0.MODALITY, 
t0.NAME, 
t0.OBSOLETE, 
t0.FACILITY_KEY
FROM PROTOCOL t0
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
                FROM CT_STUDY t2, STUDY t1
                WHERE t1.STUDY_DATE <= '2017-09-19 01:23:25.86'
                AND t2.ID = t1.ID
    AND t1.DTYPE = 'CTStudy'
    AND t0.ID = t2.PROTOCOL_KEY
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
                FROM CT_STUDY t5, STUDY t4
                WHERE t5.PROTOCOL_KEY = t0.ID
    AND t4.STUDY_DATE > '2017-09-19 01:23:25.86'
    AND t5.ID = t4.ID
    AND t4.DTYPE = 'CTStudy'
)
AND t0.FACILITY_KEY = 1;
```

Comment: What about your indexes? Can you post output of EXPLAIN please?

Comment: Find below the explain plan

Comment: | id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys                           | key                  | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra

Comment: |  1 | PRIMARY            | t0    | ref    | UK_PROTOCOL,IDX_PROTOCOL_FACILITY       | UK_PROTOCOL          | 4       | const            | 1793 | Using where

Comment: |  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t5    | ref    | PRIMARY,FK_CT_STUDY_PROTOCOL,IDX_RD_CTS | FK_CT_STUDY_PROTOCOL | 9       | serphydose.t0.ID |  193 | Using index

Comment: |  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t4    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_study_study_date,SR_MYSQL   | PRIMARY              | 8       | serphydose.t5.ID |    1 | Using where

Comment: |  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t2    | ref    | PRIMARY,FK_CT_STUDY_PROTOCOL,IDX_RD_CTS | FK_CT_STUDY_PROTOCOL | 9       | serphydose.t0.ID |  193 | Using index

Comment: |  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_study_study_date,SR_MYSQL   | PRIMARY              | 8       | serphydose.t2.ID |    1 | Using where

Answer (score 0):

Abi, please do not use comments to add information to your question. Use the edit question button instead. The more information you edit to your question, the clearer the answer can be.

It looks like you do not have any indexes in your database except the default ones on the ID created by the database and the dates.

Start experimenting by just adding an index for all columns that come after the WHERE's in your query.

I am sorry that i cannot tell you exactly what to do, i do pretty well with databases but i am not an expert for it. What i do in your case is to play around adding different indexes and reading manuals.